# Uninstalling dde gives error

Tags: apt, 20.04, dpkg, deepin-desktop-environment

I was trying to uninstall dde from ubuntu and this was the output.

```
newtron@newtron-Lenovo-V110-15ISK:~$ sudo apt-get remove ubuntudde-dde* dde* deepin*
[sudo] password for newtron: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'ubuntudde-dde' for glob 'ubuntudde-dde*'
Note, selecting 'ubuntudde-dde-extras' for glob 'ubuntudde-dde*'
Note, selecting 'dde-account-faces' for glob 'dde*'
Note, selecting 'dde-kwin' for glob 'dde*'
Note, selecting 'dde-topbar' for glob 'dde*'
Note, selecting 'dde-qt5integration' for glob 'dde*'
Note, selecting 'dde-dock-onboard-plugin' for glob 'dde*'
Note, selecting 'dde-control-center' for glob 'dde*'
Note, selecting 'dde-disk-mount-plugin' for glob 'dde*'
Note, selecting 'dde-control-center-plugin-notify' for glob 'dde*'
Note, selecting 'dde-desktop' for glob 'dde*'
Note, selecting 'dde-trash-plugin' for glob 'dde*'
Note, selecting 'dde-kwin-dev' for glob 'dde*'
Note, selecting 'dde-api-dev' for glob 'dde*'
Note, selecting 'dde-workspace' for glob 'dde*'
Note, selecting 'dde-dock-applets' for glob 'dde*'
Note, selecting 'dde-control-center-plugin-weather' for glob 'dde*'
Note, selecting 'dde-calendar' for glob 'dde*'
Note, selecting 'dde-launcher' for glob 'dde*'
Note, selecting 'dde-dock-dev' for glob 'dde*'
Note, selecting 'dde-file-manager' for glob 'dde*'
Note, selecting 'dde-polkit-agent-dev' for glob 'dde*'
Note, selecting 'dde-api' for glob 'dde*'
Note, selecting 'dde-dock' for glob 'dde*'
Note, selecting 'dde-session-ui' for glob 'dde*'
Note, selecting 'dde-daemon' for glob 'dde*'
Note, selecting 'dde-polkit-agent' for glob 'dde*'
Package 'dde-control-center-plugin-notify' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'dde-control-center-plugin-weather' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'dde-workspace' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'dde-dock-applets' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'dde-trash-plugin' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'dde-topbar' is not installed, so not removed
Note, selecting 'deepin-appstore-config' for glob 'deepin*'
Note, selecting 'deepin-system-settings-module-account' for glob 'deepin*'
Note, selecting 'deepin-desktop-environment-launcher' for glob 'deepin*'
Note, selecting 'deepin-mutter' for glob 'deepin*'
Note, selecting 'deepin-mutter-common' for glob 'deepin*'
Note, selecting 'deepin-desktop-base' for glob 'deepin*'
Note, selecting 'deepin-anything-dev' for glob 'deepin*'
Note, selecting 'deepin-wm-switcher' for glob 'deepin*'
Note, selecting 'deepin-wallpapers' for glob 'deepin*'
Note, selecting 'deepin-anything-dkms' for glob 'deepin*'
Note, selecting 'deepin-screen-recorder' for glob 'deepin*'
Note, selecting 'deepin-gettext-tools' for glob 'deepin*'
Note, selecting 'deepin-voice-recorder' for glob 'deepin*'
Note, selecting 'deepin-turbo' for glob 'deepin*'
Note, selecting 'deepin-desktop-environment-desktop' for glob 'deepin*'
Note, selecting 'deepin-session' for glob 'deepin*'
Note, selecting 'deepin-terminal' for glob 'deepin*'
Note, selecting 'deepin-wm' for glob 'deepin*'
Note, selecting 'deepin-icon-theme' for glob 'deepin*'
Note, selecting 'deepin-topbar' for glob 'deepin*'
Note, selecting 'deepin-image-viewer' for glob 'deepin*'
Note, selecting 'deepin-screenshot' for glob 'deepin*'
Note, selecting 'deepin-system-monitor' for glob 'deepin*'
Note, selecting 'deepin-shortcut-viewer' for glob 'deepin*'
Note, selecting 'deepin-menu' for glob 'deepin*'
Note, selecting 'deepin-metacity' for glob 'deepin*'
Note, selecting 'deepin-desktop-schemas' for glob 'deepin*'
Note, selecting 'deepin-metacity-common' for glob 'deepin*'
Note, selecting 'deepin-calculator' for glob 'deepin*'
Note, selecting 'deepin-desktop-environment-dock' for glob 'deepin*'
Note, selecting 'deepin-gtk-theme' for glob 'deepin*'
Note, selecting 'deepin-screensaver' for glob 'deepin*'
Note, selecting 'deepin-movie' for glob 'deepin*'
Note, selecting 'deepin-anything-server' for glob 'deepin*'
Note, selecting 'deepin-notifications' for glob 'deepin*'
Note, selecting 'deepin-default-gsettings' for glob 'deepin*'
Note, selecting 'deepin-anything-libs' for glob 'deepin*'
Note, selecting 'deepin-anything-server-dev' for glob 'deepin*'
Note, selecting 'deepin-picker' for glob 'deepin*'
Note, selecting 'deepin-turbo-booster' for glob 'deepin*'
Note, selecting 'deepin-screensaver-xscreensaver-data' for glob 'deepin*'
Note, selecting 'deepin-deb-installer' for glob 'deepin*'
Note, selecting 'deepin-music' for glob 'deepin*'
Note, selecting 'deepin-turbo-dev' for glob 'deepin*'
Note, selecting 'deepin-sound-theme' for glob 'deepin*'
Package 'deepin-system-settings-module-account' is not installed, so not removed
Note, selecting 'deepin-desktop-base' instead of 'deepin-appstore-config'
Package 'deepin-default-gsettings' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'deepin-session' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'deepin-wm-switcher' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'deepin-desktop-environment-desktop' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'deepin-desktop-environment-dock' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'deepin-desktop-environment-launcher' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'dde-calendar' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'deepin-calculator' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'deepin-deb-installer' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'deepin-gettext-tools' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'deepin-image-viewer' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'deepin-movie' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'deepin-music' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'deepin-notifications' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'deepin-picker' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'deepin-screenshot' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'deepin-shortcut-viewer' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'deepin-terminal' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'deepin-voice-recorder' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'dde-api-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'dde-dock-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'dde-kwin-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'dde-polkit-agent-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'deepin-anything-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'deepin-anything-server-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'deepin-screen-recorder' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'deepin-system-monitor' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'deepin-topbar' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'deepin-turbo-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'ubuntudde-dde-extras' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  avfs bamfdaemon blur-effect cgroup-tools cryptsetup cryptsetup-bin
  cryptsetup-initramfs cryptsetup-run dkms dpa-ext-gnomekeyring enchant
  engrampa engrampa-common eom eom-common ethtool ffmpegthumbnailer flatpak
  fonts-symbola gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1 gir1.2-eom-1.0 gir1.2-gtksource-3.0
  gir1.2-pluma-1.0 hwinfo imwheel laptop-mode-tools libappstream-glib8
  libburn4 libcgroup1 libdde-network-utils libdframeworkdbus2 libdisomaster
  libdmr0.1 libdtkcore2 libdtkwidget2 libenchant1c2a libffmpegthumbnailer4v5
  libgle3 libgnome-keyring-common libgnome-keyring0 libgranite-common
  libgranite5 libgsettings-qt1 libgtksourceview-3.0-1
  libgtksourceview-3.0-common libhd21 libisoburn1 libisofs6 libjemalloc2
  libjpeg-turbo-progs libjte2 libkf5networkmanagerqt6 libkf5screen-bin
  libkf5screen7 liblightdm-qt5-3-0 libmate-desktop-2-17
  libmate-panel-applet-4-1 libmatedict6 libmatekbd-common libmatekbd4
  libmatemixer-common libmatemixer0 libmpv1 libostree-1-1 libpeony3
  libproxychains4 libqt5-ukui-style1 libqt5charts5 libqt5concurrent5
  libqt5designer5 libqt5help5 libqt5webkit5 libqt5xdg3 libqt5xdgiconloader3
  libudisks2-qt5 libukui-kwin4-effect-builtins1 libukui-kwineffects12
  libukui-kwinglutils12 libukui-kwinxrenderutils12 libx86emu2 libxcb-ewmh2
  libxdo3 mate-calc mate-calc-common mate-desktop mate-user-guide mate-utils
  mate-utils-common mpv net-tools onboard onboard-common onboard-data
  papirus-icon-theme parchives peony peony-admin peony-common
  peony-extension-computer-view peony-extensions peony-open-terminal
  peony-set-wallpaper peony-share pluma pluma-common proxychains4
  python3-pyqt5 python3-pyxattr python3-sip qt5-gtk2-platformtheme
  qt5-styles-ukui qt5-ukui-platformtheme qt5dxcb-plugin redshift rtmpdump
  sdparm socat ttf-unifont ubuntukylin-theme ubuntukylin-wallpapers
  ubuntukylin-wallpapers-focal user-setup xdotool xscreensaver-data
  xscreensaver-data-extra xscreensaver-gl xscreensaver-gl-extra youtube-dl
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  dde-account-faces dde-api dde-control-center dde-daemon dde-desktop
  dde-disk-mount-plugin dde-dock dde-dock-onboard-plugin dde-file-manager
  dde-kwin dde-launcher dde-polkit-agent dde-qt5integration dde-session-ui
  deepin-anything-dkms deepin-anything-libs deepin-anything-server
  deepin-desktop-base deepin-desktop-schemas deepin-gtk-theme
  deepin-icon-theme deepin-menu deepin-metacity deepin-metacity-common
  deepin-mutter deepin-mutter-common deepin-screensaver
  deepin-screensaver-xscreensaver-data deepin-sound-theme deepin-turbo
  deepin-turbo-booster deepin-wallpapers deepin-wm libdde-file-manager
  libdeepin-metacity-private3 libdeepin-mutter0g libdeepin-wm0 startdde
  ubuntudde-dde
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 39 to remove and 62 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 367 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 492889 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing ubuntudde-dde (1.1) ...
Removing dde-file-manager (5.0.0-2) ...
Removing deepin-anything-server (5.0.1-4) ...
userdel: user 'deepin-anything-server' does not exist
Failed on delete user deepin-anything-server
dpkg: error processing package deepin-anything-server (--remove):
 installed deepin-anything-server package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 deepin-anything-server
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

and the proccess interrupted. Is there any way to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: The issue per the error seems to be this "userdel: user 'deepin-anything-server' does not exist" and then it goes to "Failed on delete user deepin-anything-server" and then stops. Im guessing apt purge does the same?

Comment: yeah exactly. apt purge did same then i assumed that the problem is with the remove script. and i edited teh script and then problem solve. The dde wasn't completely installed in my device that's why the remover script failed. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: What happens if you create the user for it to delete so its happy? Had to do something like it for a removal to get it to complete correctly.

Comment: I didn't think about it. can't it be a bug of dde? or any function that requires a complete dde installation(as I mentioned before my installation was broken)?

Comment: yeah you were right the package wasn't removed completely. So now I'm gonna try your solution. Thanks

Comment: @SimpliFixed Thanks. Your solution adding a user to delete fixed the problem. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

solved the problem by using `synaptic package manager` by simply searching for `deepin-anything-server` and then mark for completely removal